# Tensorflow CNN is predicting only one class

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I created a custom CNN using tensorflow to perform 3 class classification. I tried a dataset with no class imbalance. But the CNN classification report(from sklearn) shows that the CNN is predicting a single class only.

Architecture of CNN:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 1), padding='same', data_format = 'channels_last'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
```

I tried changing lr, did add BatchNormalization and dropout.Also added L2 regularization term but nothing changes the result.

This is the classification report after running it for 10 epochs. Each class has 10000 samples each. Same was happeneing when I tried using pytorch.

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

          no       0.00      0.00      0.00     10000
      sphere       0.33      1.00      0.50     10000
        vort       0.00      0.00      0.00     10000

    accuracy                           0.33     30000
   macro avg       0.11      0.33      0.17     30000
weighted avg       0.11      0.33      0.17     30000
```

Funny thing is that sometimes the class which is being predicted changes but the result remains same.

I also have shuffled my dataset:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=train_len).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should ask this question in a place dedicated to machine learning, such as Cross Validated or the Data Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: That looks strange. Could you please provide the training data(input and labels) shape. What are the parameters you have used to compile the model?

Comment: I was doing the GSOC assignment for ML4SCI and they provided the data to perform 3 class classification. Further I tried tweaking learning rate, epochs, early stopping and others but nothing worked I find it strange too. I have the dataset on kaggle and could provide you with the link if u wish to help me further.